Issue with Inner Loop Modifying Outer Loop Variables in Python
I am having a problem where an inner loop rewrites variables in the outer one, specifically when working with a list representing a Tic-tac-toe board. I want to place "X" in each empty position one at a time without modifying the already modified board. However, it seems that the inner loop keeps affecting the outer loop variable and variables that have something with it.(positions and copies of the variable)
Here’s a snippet of my code:
def occurrences(s, lst):
    return (i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e == s)

positions = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

for board in positions:
    for i in range(board.count(" ")):

        occ = list(occurrences(" ", board))[0]
        board[occ] = "X"
        print(board[0:3])
        print(board[3:6])
        print(board[6:])
        print("---------------------")

Expected Output:
['X', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
[' ', 'X', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
[' ', ' ', 'X']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
...

Actual Output:
['X', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
['X', 'X', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
['X', 'X', 'X']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
...

Question:
I expected the output to show "X" being placed in each empty position one by one, without modifying previous placements. However, it seems that each iteration of the inner loop is affecting the board variable from the outer loop.
I understand that there are different ways to approach this problem, but I would like to know why Python behaves this way and how I can prevent this from happening.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Why does positions have a nested list?

board[occ] = "X" modifies the list in place. If you don't want to modify positions, you should make a copy of board before assigning to it.

What's the point of the outer list? There's only one element in positions.

I wanted to create a program that would create every possible combination of a tic-tac-toe position. I wanted to start with one "X" try every possible combination where it can be placed, then from each of those positions do the same but with an "O"...

I've tried using a copy of board and use that but even so board and position[i] was changed

I want to expand to the number of symbols used (ex. 2"X" and 2"O" )it at to some kind of recursion

Then you're probably not making the copy correctly. board = board.copy() should work.

I'm not sure how you expect this to work. When you call occurrences(" ", board) you expect it to be using the board with the updated X spots. So of course when you add another X you're modifying the board.

It seems like you need two copies of board. One that accumulates all the X's so you can find the first unoccupied place, and another with all blanks so you can show the board with just the new X.

as an aside, your function occurrences doesn't return what you want, it surely can be improved

Yes, that helped, thank you.
